# Position text in right, center and right side of a textbox

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2011

How do I position a text in a textbox like in the footer/header?

So I can have text at the right, the center and the left of the textbox **at the same time.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Word you can set Left, Center and Right Tab stops. The default is the Left Tab stop. To get text on the Left, Center and Right hand sides of the text box set a Center Tab stop in the center (on the ruler) and a Right Tab stop on the far right and hit the TAB key to move between them...

[image: Screenshot of a text box in Word showing Left / Center / Right text]

The Header / Footer have these tab stops set by default.